# Problem in working out a claim related to ideals.

Tags: ring-theory

I have just started studying ideals from Malik,Mordeson and Sen's Abstract Algebra. In this book it has been claimed that "If $R$ be a ring and $x \in R$ then smallest ideal $(x)$ containing the element $x$ is of the form

$\{rx + xs + \sum_{i=1}^{m} s_{i} x t_{i} + nx | r, s, s_{i}, t_{i} \in R; m \in \mathbb {N} , n \in \mathbb {Z} \}$.

But I find difficulty to show that the above is an ideal.In fact when I multiply $r_{1} \in R$ with any element of the set then I am unable to show that the resulting is in the set because of the terms $r_{1} . (rx)$ and $r_{1} . (nx)$.

Please give me a hint about what is my fault, how to proceed etc.Then I will definitely retry it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using the axioms of a ring, $r_1\cdot (rx)=(r_1 r)\cdot x$ and $r_1\cdot(nx)=n(r_1\cdot x)$.

Comment: Ooo...sorry.I had to thought a bit more before asking this silly one.

Comment: I think if $R$ contains the identity then the above set takes the form $\{\sum_{i=1}^{m} s_{i} x t_{i} | s_{i}, t_{i} \in R, 1 \leq i \leq m ; m \in \mathbb {N} \}$.Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because now you can write other terms in the summation in the form of $s_i x t_i$ for some $s_i$ and $t_i$.

Comment: Moreover if $R$ is commutative then the set becomes $\{rx | r \in R \}$.